# Specializing member template when class has several template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In the following class template, we can specialize member `Foo::Bar()` for a certain type, say `T` = `int`:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar()
    {
       std::cout << "generic Bar()" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
void Foo<int>::Bar()
{
    std::cout << "specialized Bar()" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo<char> generic_foo;
    Foo<int> specialized_foo;

    generic_foo.Bar();
    specialized_foo.Bar();

    return 0;
}
```

How can we do the same if class Foo has several template parameters:

```
template <typename T, int N>
class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar()
    {
       std::cout << "generic Bar()" << std::endl;
    }
};

// How can we specialize Foo::Bar() for T = int?

int main()
{
    Foo<char, 0> generic_foo;
    Foo<int, 0> specialized_foo;

    generic_foo.Bar();
    specialized_foo.Bar();

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried several alternatives to specialize `Foo::Bar()` for `T` = `int`, including:

```
template<int N>
void Foo<int, N>::Bar()
{
    std::cout << "specialized Bar()" << std::endl;
}
```

but the compiler refused them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no partial specialization of template functions. You should specialize `class`.

```
template<int N>
class Foo<int, N>
{
public:
   void Bar()
   {
      std::cout << "specialized Bar()" << std::endl;
   }
};
```

Comment: Oh, so if Foo contains 10 other function members but only Bar() needs to be specialized with T=int, the definitions of all those 10 functions need to be duplicated?

Comment: @user1387866 yes, if you want to specialize only 1 parameter, not both. You can also write another class, that implements methods and inherit from it.